# Obtener el número de veces que un enlace ha sido compartido

Tags: php

He visto en varias webs que en los artículos incluyen el número de veces que se ha compartido el artículo en redes sociales. Sé que hay páginas para obtener el dato, pero no he sido capaz de parsearlo con PHP porque lo tienen bloqueado. ¿Existe alguna forma de hacerlo o es necesario pagar por ello?

Comment: O generás un botón para compartir y guardás cada vez que se hace click, o generás un enlace "diferente", y contás cuántas veces se accede a ese enlace... Quizás no termino de entender la pregunta... Fijate el caso de SO. Debajo de tu pregunta está el enlace para compartir, con una URL *especial* que sigue el formato `sitio/q/<id>/<usuario>` y con eso mantiene una cuenta de cuántas veces se accedió a la pregunta `<id>` por un enlace compartido por `<usuario>` (e incluso otorga medallas por eso).

Comment: @Mariano Podría hacerlo manual como dices, pero no sería correcto. Porque puede ocurrir que alguien de al botón de compartir pero no acabe de hacerlo.

Comment: Yo uso addthis, que es gratuito y te genera el el código. El problema es que tienes que cargar su js de manera externa y  el certificado SSL de la web no le gusta mucho

Comment: @JetLag Por eso está la segunda opción, que sólo cuenta las visitas... También podrías hacer que tu página sea la que "comparta" efectivamente, ya sea encargándose de generar la publicación en twitter/facebook/donde sea, pidiéndole al usuario sus credenciales, o incluso, podría ser tu propia red donde se esté compartiendo (ej: DISQUS)... Son muchas las alternativas

Comment: @Jose nunca lo usé. ¿Cuenta clicks en compartir o visitas efectivas?

Comment: Cuenta las veces que se ha compartido. Si haces click, pero no terminas de compartir no te lo cuenta